# How to get a single PDF document from Doxygen?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, doxygen, documentation-generation, pdflatex

When I generate Doxygen documentation in PDF format, I get plenty of different files with a single diagram in each.
Is it possible to obtain a single PDF document, organized as a book, roughly as the HTML version?
Is it possible to get it automatically, i.e. without dealing manually with the latex files?

Thank's!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

See [Converting a LaTeX document to a PDF document](https://web.archive.org/web/20111228024353/http://www.msi.umn.edu/software/tex/help/pdf.html).

When Doxygen is finished processing, in the latex directory there's a file called 'refman.tex'.

There are three ways you can use that file to get 'a book' out of Doxygen:

- LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf

  latex myfile

  dvips myfile

  ps2pdf myfile.ps
- LaTeX -> dvipdfm

  latex myfile

  dvipdfm myfile
- pdflatex (or pdftex for plain TeX)

  pdflatex myfile

Answer (score 25):

Assuming that doxygen is configured correctly, under Linux:

```
doxygen
cd latex
make
```

The generated file will be **refman.pdf** unless it's configured otherwise.

Answer (score 22):

Using Doxygen 1.8.4+ (on Windows), there is also a make.bat script so you don't even need to open the command line.

1. Configure Doxygen for LaTeX output.

   `GENERATE_LATEX         = YES
   LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
   OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       =`
2. Set up all your images for LaTeX output.

   `\image html application.jpg
   \image latex application.eps "My application" width=10cm`
3. Run Doxygen.
4. Run `{OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}\{LATEX_OUTPUT}\make.bat.`
5. Open `{OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}\{LATEX_OUTPUT}\refman.pdf`.

If refman.pdf is not created, run make.bat from a command window and read the errors.

Errors like:
`'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`...
Mean that you do not have the [prerequisites](https://www.tug.org/interest.html#free) to run latex at all.  Other errors may be due to missing latex packages or doxygen bugs causing invalid .tex files.

Once you have all the prerequisites installed, and a good version of doxygen, the simpler procedure should work every time.

Comment: make.bat is generated by the windows version, on Linux the generated file is called Makefile.

Comment: Do you have to pass that to make, or is it a script?

Comment: It's executed by make

Comment: On Linux, type "make" in the "latex" directory.
The generated document is "refman.pdf".

Comment: In my case all the image specified via \image are missing. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you specifying separate image commands for latex and html output?

Comment: You need to have a separate image command for each format of output:  http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdimage

Comment: The other easy thing to check is your image path.  http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_image_path

Comment: In Cygwin after I run `make`, I get error message: `pdflatex command not found`. Any idea how to make it work in Cygwin?

Comment: Did you install LaTeX?  Is it in the path for Cygwin?

Comment: This did not work for me. I ran the `make.bat` file, but it did not create any output folder in the latex folder

Comment: did it print out any errors?  run from a console rather than double-clicking so you can see what it prints to screen.

Comment: It won't create a new folder, just a new file.  Your Doxygen output needs to output a latex folder.  Inside the latex folder is your make.bat, and in the same folder you should find refman.pdf.

Answer (score 14):

Patel is right - you need to run Doxygen, then Latex of some sort to create the single doc.

For me, using Doxygen 1.7.3, the root file for the latex build seems to be "refman.tex".

Doxygen creates a Makefile, too, so if you've got make (I don't on my Win7 box), you can just type `make` in the latex directory.

I point my TeXnicCenter app at refman.tex, and build that way.

Hope this helps,

-Matt

Comment: Doxygen has also a make.bat on Windows systems and theer is a Makefile (for a *nix make)

Answer (score 6):

Other people didn't mention a detail:

For the pdflatex route to work, your current working directory needs to be the generated latex folder, otherwise you get errors like `doxygen.sty cannot be found`.

Answer (score 1):

I would add one additional advise. **Don't ignore the latex warnings**. pdflatex can fail to produce an output file as well as any meaningful errors.

I had a similar annoying situation and just fixing all the warnings helped to produce the correct output file without any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

### Generating PDF with Make

I followed the steps mentioned above and successfully avoided error messages while generating the PDF using these steps:

1. After running `Doxygen`, I navigated to the `./latex` directory created by this command.
2. There is a `Makefile` inside the `latex` directory, I added the flag `-interaction=nonstopmode` to `LATEX_CMD`, as shown below:

```
LATEX_CMD?=pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode
MKIDX_CMD?=makeindex
BIBTEX_CMD?=bibtex
LATEX_COUNT?=8
MANUAL_FILE?=refman
.....etc
```

3. Finally, I ran make inside the latex directory, which now accepts the nonstop mode flag.

```bash
# Inside the latex directory
make
```

**edit** From comment by @albert:

> There is an easier way as doxygen has the setting `LATEX_BATCHMODE` (since doxygen version 1.9.7) and this can have as one of its possibilities: `NON_STOP` which also uses the `nonstopmode` but inside the latex document (and set by doxygen in refman.tex, so you don't have to set it in your `Makefile` or `make.bat`

Comment: There is an easier way as doxygen has the setting `LATEX_BATCHMODE` (since doxygen version 1.9.7) and this can have as one of its possibilities: `NON_STOP` which also uses the `nonstopmode` but inside the latex document (and set by doxygen in refman.tex, so you don't have to set it in your `Makefile` or `make.bat`)

Comment: Ohh, Wow, 
I am so happy to get your answer, I spend useless mints just to write a sed command to write to this Makefile and append the flag of --interaction=nonstopmode.
Thank you very much for sharing,

Comment: Must be some sort of problem in the way pdflatex handles an option versus a setting in the LaTeX file. Is this persistent, If so you could post a question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Albert
I apologize for the earlier confusion; it appears I made an error in my setup. , I realized that I incorrectly used 'YES' instead of 'NON_STOP' for the LATEX_BATCHMODE option. I can now confirm that the error was on my end due to my misunderstanding. Thank you for your support.