# pagebreak in markdown while creating pdf

Tags: markdown, doxygen

I am creating a pdf of markdown text file using doxygen (1.8.6). Now I want to get page break at specific stage in markdown file, I used this [link](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

In the given link they have mentioned to use '>' for line break. But they haven't mentioned about page break. Yes I can use '>' for page break as well but I have to write this symbol 5 or more times on markdown text file and that makes markdown file in weird look. Is there any other ways to get page breaks in markdown files?

Comment: Did you have a go at code like:
My Main Page {#mainpage}
============
This is the text on the first page
\latexonly
\newpage
\endlatexonly
This is the text on the second page

Comment: @albert I didn't find any mainpage keyword in latex folder

Comment: The example I gave generates a mainpage consisting of 2 pages. The important part for you would be \latexonly ....\endlatexonly. When you place my example in a file (e.g. aa.md) you can see the 2 pages when you generated the latex output.

Comment: @albert yeah now I got it earlier I didn't use the latexonly command in text file .Now I got it thanks

Answer (score 97, accepted):

I encountered the same and solve it by inserting

\pagebreak

It's actually a LaTeX command, rather than a Markdown one.

Comment: this works well with pandoc. inserts a page break in the latex pdf without interfering with the html rendering.

Comment: thx, I was just looking for that :) It works in R's knit tool too.

Comment: Markdown does not natively support Latex, whereas it does natively support HTML and CSS. This is why @tomodian's answer below has more up votes. This solution works in some cases (notably in R Markdown, as Tetlanesh mentions), but not in all. Choose tomodian's answer below... it is more portable.

Comment: Since the OP question is about general markdown I feel like this answer won't work/be useful for most folks. @tomodian's answer is the best IMO.

Comment: Note that `\newpage` could be a better choice. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/740

Answer (score 334):

Since Markdown accepts plain HTML and CSS, simply add this line wherever you want to force page break.

```
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
```

If your Markdown editor have trouble exporting PDF correctly, first try to export as HTML, then open with your browser and print as PDF.

Comment: This is the correct answer. These kind of style 'hacks' is probably why John accepted HTML/CSS

Comment: This is the correct answer. And it works with daring fireballs Markdown well

Comment: This has been the most applicable and widely supported solution I've tested.

Comment: The w3schools entry on page-break-before says, "Note: You cannot use this property on an empty <div> or on absolutely positioned elements."  I would use it if it worked (but alas not in Jupyter).)

Comment: I use this with puppeteer, works great. <hr style="page-break-after: always;"/>

Comment: works on atom with plugin https://atom.io/packages/markdown-to-pdf

Comment: This did not work for me at all. The accepted LaTex answer did work.

Comment: `page-break-after` is now deprecated, please replace by `break-after` ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-after))

Comment: Worked for me when using [pdfforge](https://www.pdfforge.org/online/en/markdown-to-pdf) to convert `.md` document to `.pdf` after checking the **Page break** option.

Answer (score 38):

I Know that this is a dead question, but I've found a way that I think can be useful for other than me.

You can use the command \pagebreak inside an invisible  element. In this way it works with latex and with html.

```
<div style="page-break-after: always; visibility: hidden"> 
\pagebreak 
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use doxygen commands like `\htmlonly` with the `<div>`etc. and `\latexonly´ with `\pagebrak`,instead of this trick.

Comment: because this trick is portable outside doxygen and you can use it even with pandoc.

Answer (score 10):

### Blockquotes vs. line breaks

`>` is not used for line breaks in Markdown. It's used for blockquotes. For example, the following Markdown code

```
> A man provided with paper, pencil, and rubber, and
> subject to strict discipline, is in effect a universal machine.
```

becomes

> A man provided with paper, pencil, and rubber, and
>   subject to strict discipline, is in effect a universal machine.

(This is a [quote from Alan Turing](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Alan_Turing).)

Note how it is rendered with a yellow background by Stack Overflow. If you examine the generated markup you will find `<blockquote>` tags being used.

Line breaks can usually be inserted by ending a line with two or more spaces (Markdown syntax) or by using raw `<br>` tags (most Markdown processors allow inline HTML). For example (using `␣` to represent a space), this Markdown

```
123 Fake Street␣␣
Springfield, USA
```

becomes

123 Fake Street
Springfield, USA

### Page breaks

Since the original specification Markdown was designed for HTML output (which doesn't have the concept of pages) there is no support for page breaks.

Doxygen [uses LaTeX to generate its PDFs](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/output.html). It doesn't seem to support inline LaTeX¹, but you should be able to modify the intermediate `.tex` file and then use `pdflatex` to generate your PDF:

1. Use Doxygen to generate a `.tex` file
2. Edit the `.tex` file manually add `\newpage` wherever you want page breaks
3. Run `pdflatex documentation.tex`
4. Examine `documentation.pdf`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099572/how-to-get-a-single-pdf-document-from-doxygen) may be a useful reference for step 3 above.

¹Doxygen [does support inline LaTeX *formulas*](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/formulas.html), but I wasn't able to find any mention of arbitrary inline LaTeX commands like `\newpage` that operate in the text environment.

Comment: Hey Initially I went through .tex file approach , though I wanted to use pure markdown approach for pdf generation anyway and yes I also tried \newpage but that didn't work .

Comment: There is no pure Markdown approach since Markdown doesn't include syntax for page breaks. Although there are many Markdown extensions, I am not aware of any that add support for page breaks. You could try something like Pandoc which [supports inline LaTeX](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#raw-tex), but I imagine you're using Doxygen for its ability to extract documentation blocks from source code, which Pandoc doesn't do. Maybe I'm wrong about that...

Answer (score 10):

In my Markdown document, `page-break-after` sometimes left a heading or two still on the same page. In those cases `page-break-before` worked to properly put everything after the `<div>` on the next page:

`<div style="page-break-before:always"></div>`

Answer (score 7):

Though these answers work - they kind of break one of the goals of Markdown (MD), which is to be very readable as a straight text document as well as being able to be formatted into more rich presentations.

As soon as you start embedding a bunch of HTML/CSS in the text you lose the first aspect of MD.  You might as well use Word, Libre, HTML/CSS, etc.

I think MD would do well to add a page break sequence.  Something like:
`<<<<>>>>` or similar to the formatting operators.  I use that in my MD text.  It doesn't cause a page break in the PDF or HTML converters, but it's recognizable in both those and the plain-text forms.

Answer (score 3):

A last resort workaround is to manually edit the HTML output to render to PDF as you want.

Answer (score 3):

To make tomodian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29642392/13747125) slightly cleaner, you can reference a CSS class:

words.md:

```
<div class="pagebreak" />
```

style.css:

```css
.pagebreak { page-break-after: always; }
```

Comment: (You could even denote the empty tag more succinctly: `<div class="pagebreak" />`.)

Comment: Thanks @greybeard! I guessed there would be a shorter way to close the tag.

Comment: I know this is old but it's always good to remember, [div isn't self closing](https://jakearchibald.com/2023/against-self-closing-tags-in-html/#:~:text=would%20be%20a%20self%2Dclosing%20div%2C%20but%20not%20in%20HTML). [Check also](https://jakearchibald.com/2023/against-self-closing-tags-in-html/#:~:text=Outside%20of%20foreign%20content%2C%20elements%20that%20self%2Dclose%20will%20always%20self%2Dclose.%20All%20other%20elements%2C%20won%27t)