# How to put markdown pages onto new PDF pages with Pandoc?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, pdflatex, xelatex

Pandoc allows a user to translate multiple Markdown input files into one PDF file.

```
pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -o test.pdf *.md
```

With this call, all Markdown pages are continuously listed in the PDF output without any new-page. I would like to start a new PDF page per Markdown file.

How to add a `\newpage` after or before every inserted Markdown file?

Comment: How about `for f in *.md; do cat "$f"; printf "\\newpage"; done | pandoc --pdf... -o ...`

Comment: Or maybe `pandoc ... <(gawk '1; ENDFILE{print "\\newpage"}' *.md)`

Comment: Or `gawk '1; ENDFILE{print "\\newpage"}' *.md | pandoc ...`

Comment: @MarkSetchell `\newpage` is a LaTeX command. If added to a Markdown file, it won't be interpreted as LaTeX content, right?

Comment: Oh I see. I understood your question to mean that you knew `/newpage` worked but you just weren't sure how to feed it in between markdown documents. I wasn't sure if it would work either, so I just commented rather than answering. I'll think some more today...

Comment: Maybe try this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/29642392/2836621

Comment: @Paebbels yes, pandoc supports TeX inside markdown, see https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#raw-htmltex

Comment: @Paebbels see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/52131435

Comment: @MarkSetchell please compose an answer so I can accept it as a solution, because Pandoc accepts embedded LaTeX code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use **GNU awk**, i.e. `gawk`, with multiple files, it has an extension that triggers at the end of each file so you can use that to insert *"newpage"* commands like this:

```
gawk '1; ENDFILE{print "\\newpage"}' *.md | pandoc --pdf-engine=xelatex -o test.pdf
```

The `1` in `gawk` evaluates to "True" which causes `gawk` to do its default action, which is to print the current line, so that means all lines get printed, in addition to the *"newpage"* commands at the end of each file.

---

You can probably get the same result with GNU `sed` if you add the `-s` option to treat each document as separate, so you get a separate *"last line"* for each document:

```
sed -se '$a\\\newpage' doc*.md | pandoc ...
```

Comment: While this answer is correct in adding a raw LaTeX command like `\newpage` into the Markdown file to solve the problem, I would like to see a more neutral answer. Using `awk` or `sed` is a Linux-biased answer not very suitable for Pandoc users on Windows platforms. Otherwise it's a good answer.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that from your question. I'll have a think about Windows-specific solutions, but for the moment, I do know you can install `gawk` on Windows easily enough.

Comment: You can add multiple sections to your answer. 1) a gneric answer about `\newpage` and Pandoc accepting embedded raw LaTeX commands. 2) a linux-based answer using `gawk` or `sed`. 3) a Windows suitable answer using e.g. PowerShell commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without Pandoc with simple [Python script](https://github.com/vb64/markdown-pdf) like this:

```
pip install markdown-pdf

from markdown_pdf import Section, MarkdownPdf

pdf = MarkdownPdf()

# each section (content of single md file) starts from new page in pdf file
pdf.add_section(Section(open("file1.md").read()))  # page 1
pdf.add_section(Section(open("file2.md").read()))  # page 2

pdf.save("out.pdf")
```